# Cannot read property '$axios' of undefined nuxtjs vuex

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

I stumbled upon this bug in my codebase and trying to see if anyone can fix it.

following is my listings/actions.js

```
export const fetchFeaturedListings = ({ commit }) => {
  this.$axios.get("/featured").then(response => {
    console.log(response.data.data);
    commit("listings/setFeaturedListings", response.data.data);
  });
};
```

I am constantly getting the following error.

Cannot read property '$axios' of undefined

I've searched everywhere, and still not able to find an answer. Hope someone can help.

Comment: Need more details like what is your environment? Webpack? Node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For arrow function vuex can't set 'this'. Try to use standart functions.

```
export const fetchFeaturedListings = function({ commit }){
  this.$axios.get("/featured").then(response => {
    console.log(response.data.data);
    commit("listings/setFeaturedListings", response.data.data);
  });
};
```

Comment: Yes, to be clear, every time you use an arrow function you override the `this` context.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an arrow function, which means `this` comes from the outer scope. If `$axios` doesn't exist in that outer scope, this is why you see this error.

Answer (score 0):

Just like jedmao said, you are accessing a wrong `this`. suggest you just import `axios` and use it.